# How do you reduce wind gust sounds from video?

Tags: premiere, audio, audio-recording, noise-reduction, noise

So I've looked at a bunch of videos and all they describe is how to remove ambient wind sounds so that you can hear someone talk.  Or how to remove the low hum of wind.  And if it's the wind sound is too loud, it's impossible to remove.  That's not what I am looking for.

I have an outdoor video and I would like to keep most of those sounds.  My only issue is that when the wind gusts, it is really loud.  I'm afraid it would hurt someone's ears if they have headphones plugged in.  I would just like to tone it down.  When my video is soft, there is nothing changed.  When my video is loud, that is reduced a bit.

Additionally, is there also a way to round out or smooth the wind noise a bit? I would imagine reducing how loud a video gets while keeping the video the same when it's quiet would solve this issue as well.

I have Adobe Premier.

Comment: For future reference it's best to use a windscreen, put the microphone as close as possible to the sound source and use a directional microphones. Sadly it seems as though you have already recorded it. In that case you might be able to improve it in an audio editor or better yet have you considered re-recording what you said in the video in a quiet room?

Comment: No there's no words in it.  I have premier pro, all I need to do is limit the sound intensity.  Not sure which effect to choose.

Comment: Now I understand. Note that a windscreen would have helped with this use case as well and that way you don't have to mess around with software. In addition it might outperform the best that you can do on the computer. I understand that you have already recorded your audio and video so you need to fix what you already have.

Comment: If there's no sync sounds, maybe you could go to freesound.org and get some ambient sound that matches the pictures and use that instead.

Comment: If you have an audio editor that can host VST plugins (LMMS is one that is free), I recommend Tokyo Dawn Labs TDR Nova plugin (also free). This is a dynamic eq., which works well for things like removing wind rumble. https://www.tokyodawn.net/tokyo-dawn-labs/

Answer (score 1):

Two possible ideas. When writing this answering I'm thinking in terms of the capabilities provided by Audacity but I think the same concept will work with other software.

1. Pick a silent part of the video with only the wind sound but no other sounds that you would like to keep, select that as the noise profile then apply noise reduction whenever there is the wind noise.
2. Apply a high pass filter to the audio. This will help reduce the effects of the wind noise. Again consider only applying this when there is wind.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about video, i would consider the ffmpeg audio filter. The wind noise spectrum mentions in this [product white-paper](https://www.intricon.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/Audion-16-White-Paper-Wind-Noise-23037A.pdf) is below 500hz; therefore, i would suggest the ffmpeg command as

```
ffmpeg -i <input_file> -af "highpass=f=500" <output_file>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is the use case for using an audio compressor. You set a threshold, below which the compressor doesn't affect volumes, and above which it compresses the audio sound level.